# Excel if els by Color in cell. Transfer Data between sheets if conditions are true

Tags: excel, vba

Need some help to figure out how to detect if a cell is red or green. (ex :the style buttons in excel: Good, Bad, nautral.

If(b2 is Good(green), move data to X,

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: For this, Google is your solution. Much quicker of course. This is one of the solutions that Google gave on "Excel VBA cell color": http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/change-cell-background-color-using-vba-HA001136627.aspx
(You can change the color like this, but test it as well, of course.)

Comment: Hmm. I have tryd some thigs with VBA but dont give me the needed result.

Comment: Please share the code that needs fixing otherwise it is very hard for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i solved my problem this way:) No it dosent mather if the color is red,blue,green..etc
tnx anyway

Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, rRange As Range)
    Dim cSum As Long
    Dim ColIndex As Integer

```
ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each cl In rRange
  If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColIndex Then
    cSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cl, cSum)
  End If
Next cl
SumByColor = cSum
```

End Function